# I can not copy the values of my Array in another Array with Assembly (ARM)

Tags: assembly, arm

I have two arrays A and B with length = 8; I want to copy the first half of array A into the second half of array B, and the second half of array A into the first half of array B. I don't know if what i do is true.

Here is my code:

```
LDR r0 , src_address           ; Adress of array A
LDR r1 , dest_address          ; Adress of array B
LDMIA r0!, { r2, r3, r4, r5 }  ; load the first half of array A
STMDA r1!, { r5, r4, r3, r2 }  ; store it into the second half of array B 
LDMIA r0!, { r6, r7, r8, r9 }  ; load the second half of array A
STMDA r1!, { r9, r8, r7, r6 }  ; store it into the first half of array B
```

Comment: Where exactly does `dest_address` point? If it's anywhere other than the _last_ element of the array then you're clearly going to go out of bounds by using a decrement addressing mode on it.

Comment: Could you explain me how to set the last element of the array B?

Comment: Er, add 28 to it? (assuming the array is 8 words long). Though if it's fixed at 8 words then AFAICS you could just do `ldmia r0, {r2-r9}; stmia r1!, {r6-r9}; stmia r1, {r2-r5}`. Another thing, are `src_address` and `dest_address` the symbols of the actual arrays, or of variables holding pointers to them? If it's the latter, then using `adr` rather than `ldr` introduces one too many indirections and you'd end up corrupting memory around the pointer variables themselves, rather than reading and writing the array data.

Comment: The original code seems to be based on a misunderstanding: the order in which you specify the source/destination registers has no effect on order of loading/storing. It is always lowest index register from/to lowest memory address.